# Convert hour of the year into date in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I am a new Matlab user and wondering if there is any built-in operator or function which could convert the hour of the year into calendar date and time for that year. For example,

Hour 0 in year 2000 is 2000-01-01 00:00:00

Hour 1 is 2000-01-01 01:00:00

and so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I solved it. I used the addtodate function documented [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/addtodate.html).

Here is how I am doing it:

```
start=datenum(2000, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0);
curr=addtodate(start, hour_of_yr, 'hour');
disp (datestr (curr));
```

Where hour_of_yr is passed to matlab function from commandline.